# Looking for PID tuning library in Modelica

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am building a control system with the Modelica Standard Library. But I got trouble in tuning the parameters in the PID system，so I wanna use a library that could do auto-tuning for the PID system. After some searching on Google, it seems there is no such a library in Modelica.
My question: Could anyone recommend an auto-tuning library for the PID system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at `Modelica IndustrialControlSystems` (https://github.com/mbonvini/IndustrialControlSystems). It has some autotuning PID blocks.

Best regards Rene Just Nielsen