# how to do multi-loop PID Tuning in the Modelica model?

Tags: modelica, dymola

Tuning the PID parameter is crucial in the control system development, here is an example of how to do this for just one PID controller.
https://www.claytex.com/tech-blog/tuning-pid-gains-dymola-modelling/

But if there are multiple PID controllers in the Modelica model, IS there a standard procedure of tuning the parameters?

Is there a Modelica library for multiple PID controller tuning?

[image]

Comment: related or partly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59588843/looking-for-pid-tuning-library-in-modelica

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a standard procedure to tuning parameters: Likely not, as this a pretty big [area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_engineering) in engineering. It strongly depends on the type of system you need to control, although you limited to PID already, for which a set of [tuning methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) exist.

In the Dymola Manual 2 there is a section about tuning parameters using the `Design` library based on the example `Design.Optimization.Examples.ControllerDesign_F14`. The tutorial related is given in section "First optimization setup". It uses optimization and should be rather generally applicable. Also the [LinearSystems2](https://github.com/modelica/Modelica_LinearSystems2) library can be of great help, as it provides tools for controller design, e.g. a state-space representation of a model (after linearization).

Regarding your specific problem, it is a bit difficult to judge from your screenshot, but assuming it is cascaded control, [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/examples/designing-cascade-control-system-with-pi-controllers.html) should help. In case the controlled variables influence each other they should be decoupled, as e.g. shown [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f377/3fca524117400fca5d9085a8664617ec5117.pdf). If non of the before is the case and there are no strong limitations expected in the actuators manual tuning seems feasible.

BTW: Modelica is especially well suited for complex control problems as it can use the plant model to do [inverse](https://www.modelica.org/events/Conference2005/online_proceedings/Session3/Session3c3.pdf) control. But this seems to be a bit over-engineered for your application.